# Are these sentences grammatically and logically correct by using "miss not doing something"？

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning, transitivity, logic

I came across this sentence today,

> I’m the oldest child in my family and ***have missed not having an older sibling*** to lean on.

I don't think the sentence is right,because ***miss*** is mostly a transitive verb which means ***not be able to*** catch, have or experience something. So it would be conflicting in meaning if somebody "misses""not doing something". That is, the writer actually has an older sibling. However,that would be impossible.

I tried to google and found some more sentences like,

> I missed not having my parents full attention...
>
> Another time I may have missed not having a full kitchen and dishwasher.
>   ...

I'm really confused. Could anybody help?

Comment: Wait, is it "I have missed" plus a complement that is "not having an older sibling to lean on" ? But it still sounds weird...

Comment: I'm confused too.  I had to look up "sth" and sb".  Please avoid internet slang if you want those of us who only know English to understand what you mean. If this were an old-time telegraph and were being charged by the character, it might be ok.  But **s**ome**th**ing and **s**ome**b**ody are actually no extra cost.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the word [miss](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20miss) is incorrect.  I have never seen it mean **not to be able to**.  In this instance it means emotionally *notice the loss or absence of*. So the phrase, *have missed not having an older sibling*, means you really would have liked to have an older sibling, and you feel that absence.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **not having...** has  *nominal* weight, so to speak, and thus can serve as the object of transitive **missed**.

The negation does not eliminate the nominal (noun-like) force of the **-ing** form of the verb, although it makes this sentence somewhat strange.  The speaker is using **missed** idiosyncratically to mean "felt the sense of lack or loss that results from {the absence of that which is missed}".

> He missed sharing time with her.
>
> She missed chatting with her sister.

P.S. The speaker could have said

> I missed having an older sibling.

but without "I was the oldest child" to make the context clear, that statement could imply that the speaker at one time did have an older sibling.

> I missed having an older sibling to confide in, after my brother went off to university.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the verb miss means to fail to do, have, catch, hit, notice, etc.
Sometinmes, it's used to mean to regret or feel sorry. So the phrase "miss not having" means "regret not having".

The phrase  is an ambiguous phrase. So "have missed not having an older sibling" may mean:

- You haven't failed to have an older sibling.
- you have regretted not having an older sibling.

The phrase is rarely used because of its ambiguity.

Comment: You're ovelooking "I am the oldest child". That eliminates any ambiguity and renders your first paraphrase ("You haven't failed to have an older sibling") invalid.